# Dungeon defenders online

Tags: ps3, dungeon-defenders

There's an offer of Dungeon Defenders on the PS Store this weekend, but before buying it, does anyone knows if the game can still be played online?

I read on some webpages that Gamespy was shutting down (I know it's old news), however I read in some other web pages that it won't affect Dungeon Defenders.

Is online play still available on console?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are correct that Gamespy servers were officially decommissioned in May 2014. Dungeon Defenders relied on Gamespy servers for multiplayer support, and the game has not been updated to accommodate another multiplayer platform.

In short, Dungeon Defenders on PS3 cannot be played using online multiplayer. It does however have local split-screen co op, so if you're in the same room with friends you can play together.